# building the Android source, libart-compiler Error

Tags: android

I trying to build Android Source in the VMware Workstation Pro(ubuntu 15.04).

I lunch aosp_arm-eng

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.1.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.19.0-15-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.04-vivid
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=LVY48F
OUT_DIR=out
```

My problem is :

```
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:1282: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::GetReturn(art::RegisterClass)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:1425: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::AddIntrinsicSlowPath(art::CallInfo*, art::LIR*, art::LIR*)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2479: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::MarkLive(art::RegLocation)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2468: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::FlushIns(art::RegLocation*, art::RegLocation)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2557: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::GenDalvikArgsNoRange(art::CallInfo*, int, art::LIR**, int (*)(art::CompilationUnit*, art::CallInfo*, int, art::MethodReference const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, art::InvokeType), art::MethodReference const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, bool)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2591: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::GenDalvikArgsRange(art::CallInfo*, int, art::LIR**, int (*)(art::CompilationUnit*, art::CallInfo*, int, art::MethodReference const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, art::InvokeType), art::MethodReference const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, bool)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2759: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::UpdateRawLoc(art::RegLocation)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2794: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::UpdateRawLoc(art::RegLocation)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2814: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::GenExplicitNullCheck(art::RegStorage, int)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/target_x86.cc:2859: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::MarkPossibleNullPointerExceptionAfter(int, art::LIR*)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/utility_x86.cc:573: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::ScanLiteralPoolWide(art::LIR*, int, int)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/utility_x86.cc:575: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::AddWideData(art::LIR**, int, int)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/utility_x86.cc:1063: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileToMethodInlinerMap::GetMethodInliner(art::DexFile const*)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/utility_x86.cc:1065: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileMethodInliner::IsIntrinsic(unsigned int, art::InlineMethod*)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/utility_x86.cc:1063: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileToMethodInlinerMap::GetMethodInliner(art::DexFile const*)'
art/compiler/dex/quick/x86/utility_x86.cc:1065: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileMethodInliner::IsIntrinsic(unsigned int, art::InlineMethod*)'
art/compiler/dex/mir_optimization.cc:1281: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileToMethodInlinerMap::GetMethodInliner(art::DexFile const*)'
art/compiler/dex/mir_optimization.cc:1281: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileMethodInliner::GenInline(art::MIRGraph*, art::BasicBlock*, art::MIR*, unsigned int)'
art/compiler/dex/mir_analysis.cc:1082: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileToMethodInlinerMap::GetMethodInliner(art::DexFile const*)'
art/compiler/dex/mir_analysis.cc:1082: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileMethodInliner::IsSpecial(unsigned int)'
art/compiler/dex/quick_compiler_callbacks.cc:29: error: undefined reference to 'art::DexFileMethodInliner::AnalyseMethodCode(art::verifier::MethodVerifier*)'
art/compiler/compilers.cc:111: error: undefined reference to 'art::MipsCodeGenerator(art::CompilationUnit*, art::MIRGraph*, art::ArenaAllocator*)'
art/compiler/compilers.cc:124: error: undefined reference to 'art::Mir2Lir::GetMaxPossibleCompilerTemps() const'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build/core/host_shared_library_internal.mk:44: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libart-compiler.so' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libart-compiler.so] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (01:49 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I read many relate solutions, but no help!

How can I resolve this question?

Comment: how did you solve this ?